# Font awesome not working on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

Im trying to get font awesome to work in my app.

I've made a custom label to do so:

```cs
public FALabel()
{
  FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform(null, "FontAwesome", "/Assets/fontawesome-webfont.ttf#FontAwesome");      
}
```

I have added the fonts to the 2 projects.

On android it is working as expected - on IOS it does not, see the picture below.

[image]

This was supposed to be 6 different items - none of them being a question sign.

I added the font to `info.plist` and set build action to Copy always.
I verified that the font is installed on IOS with the following snippet:

```cs
private void LogFonts()
{
  foreach (NSString family in UIFont.FamilyNames)
  {
    foreach (NSString font in UIFont.FontNamesForFamilyName(family))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(@"{0}", font);
    }
  }
}
```

My font awesome unicodes are fetched from a string:

```cs
...
public static string FAGlass = "\uf000";
public static string FAMusic = "\uf001";
public static string FASearch = "\uf002";
...
```

As mentioned earlier, it works as expected on Android - what am i missing?

Relevant section of Info.plist

```xml
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
  <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Can you include your info.plist contents? You have mentioned you added the font there and can enumerate it, but it's possible there's still something wrong with the declaration. Also, my fontawesome-webfont.ttf is set to Do not Copy, build action: bundle resource and it's inside the root of the Resources folder. It works great.

Comment: Done. i only set the build action because it didnt work.. but still, the font is installed - it's wierd.

Comment: The only difference to my setup that I can see is that I have <string>fontawesome-webfont.ttf</string> and my actual font file is indeed called fontawesome-webfont.ttf

Comment: My actual font file is FontAwesome.ttf, triple checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument you pass to the Device.OnPlatform call when setting the FontFamily is the value to use on the iOS platform.
In your case you have set it to null.

I setup mine like this:

```
FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform("FontAwesome", "FontAwesome", @"/Assets/Fonts/fontawesome - webfont.ttf#FontAwesome");
//For Android, a custom renderer is required in any case, which can specify the correct font without utilizing the FontFamily property, but I prefer to specify it there as well, for clarity or if you decide to support multiple fonts
```

and it works just fine.

Comment: That's embarrassing... Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong Device order: It is iOS, Android and then Windows:

```
public static Void OnPlatform (Action iOS, Action Android, Action WinPhone, Action Default)
```

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.OnPlatform/

Comment: That's embarrassing... Thanks :D